# How can I fetch all the comments of my followings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called
`acts_as_commentable_with_threading`(https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading), and `acts_as_follower`(https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

So far, everything is working fine. All of my followings, and followers functions with no problem.

Now, I'm trying to fetch all the comments of all my following users.
So I tried this

```
@users = current_user.following_users
@comments = @users.comment_threads.order("updated_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

However, it returns this error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `comment_threads' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000000d1b7a58>):
```

Why and how can I solve this??
`acts_as_commentable_with_threading` is not supporting array objects????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [code](https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading/blob/master/lib/acts_as_commentable_with_threading.rb#L37), you'll likely need to so something like:

```
user_ids = current_user.following_users.map(&:id)
commentable = User.base_class.name.to_s
@comments = Comment.where(:user_id => user_ids, :commentable_type => commentable).order('created_at DESC')
```

The above will get the comments for an array of user_ids, rather than just one user

Comment: Thanks But I've got this error back:( `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous: SELECT id FROM `users` INNER JOIN `follows` ON `follows`.`followable_id` = `users`.`id` AND `follows`.`followable_type` = 'User' WHERE `follows`.`blocked` = 0 AND `follows`.`follower_id` = 4 AND `follows`.`follower_type` = 'User' AND `follows`.`followable_type` = 'User' AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL)):
`